# With zsh how to add autocompletion for a specific script, with autocompletion choices coming from a file?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I have written a small shell script that takes a single command line argument.

I'd like to be able to autocomplete when I start writing an argument, the autocompletion choices should come from a specific text file.

For instance if my text file contains

```
foo
foobar
```

if I start writing `my-cli fo` and press `TAB` I like zsh to show me the choices `foo` and `foobar`.

Any pointer to a relevant documentation or tutorial is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I am struggling with a similar problem, but a bit more complicated.
With a static autocomplete options file the following code works for me:

```
#compdef test

_test_comp(){
 t=($(cat /tmp/file_with_opts))
 _wanted t expl "availavle options" compadd -a t
}

_arguments -C -S  \
 '*:test_autocomplete:_test_comp'
```

This way script `test` will pickup options from `/tmp/file_with_opts`